# diffraction slot for camera obscura

Tags: optics

Please undertstand that I'm not a physics person, and my maths is terrible.
I've built a number of room-size camera obscuras, and I'm now interested in the idea of a a difraction grating as a lens, which I *think* will produce a series of stripes rather than an image.
Can anyone help?
Again, please keep it simple.

kind Regards
Oli

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iuv6hY6zsd0

Comment: mark!Thanks for that. Have more questions. Are you in the UK?

Comment: Love your intro.

Comment: Nope. I'm in the USA.